# Extract string from csv file after reading in Prolog

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

Good evening,

I am trying to read a `csv` file in Prolog containing all the countries in the world. Executing this code:

```
read_KB(R) :- csv_read_file("countries.csv",R).
```

I get a list of `Terms` of this type:

```
R = [row('Afghanistan;'), row('Albania;'), row('Algeria;'), row('Andorra;'), row('Angola;'), row('Antigua and Barbuda;'), row('Argentina;'), row('Armenia;'), row(...)|...].
```

I would like to extract only the names of each country in form of a `String` and put all of them into a `list of Strings`.
I tried this way with only the first row executing this:

```
read_KB(L) :- csv_read_file("/Users/dylan/Desktop/country.csv",R),
        give(R,L).

give([X|T],X).
```

I obtain only a Term of type `row('Afghanistan;')`

Comment: You haven't specified what to do with `T` in your definition of `give`.

Comment: You are right. I was planning to make a recursive call on the tail, or just put underscore for this particular example. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
read_KB(Names) :-
    csv_read_file('countries.csv', Rows, [separator(0';)]),
    maplist([row(Name,_), Name] >> true, Rows, Names).
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @slago can be simplified, using [arg/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3) instead of a lambda expression, making it slightly more efficient:

```
read_KB(Names) :-
    csv_read_file('countries.csv', Rows, [separator(0';)]),
    maplist(arg(1), Rows, Names).
```

Comment: How can a solution that uses the non-ISO predicates `csv_read_file/3` and `maplist/3` become standard ISO just by using `arg/3`?

Comment: @slago: well, at least **arg/3** is ISO standard, no ?

Comment: @slago:  but maybe, the lambda is ISO standard as well, I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes, `arg/3` is ISO standard. But, as I said, **simply using this predicate** in place of a lambda expression **does not make your solution an ISO standard code**.

Comment: @slago: ok, I will remove the claim about ISO compliance...